# Can connect to internet with Firefox but Chrome can't

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-connection, windows-update

I'm using Windows 7 x86 SP1.

I've been using chrome for years. But now it can't connect to internet.

I think it's because the latest windows update, which after i updated it, all of the fonts' gone. It's just symbols, but i've corrected it.

When I open Chrome, with a LAN cable plugged in, it just show the "Aw, Snap!" page. But when I'm using Firefox, the internet is running normal.

I've check my antivirus and run system scan, no virus found.

Is it because of the Chrome or my Windows is error?

**Update:** i've try on IE 11 without add-ons, it works. And whenever i open Chrome, it still shows the "aw snap" and all of the extensions get crashed.

Comment: I would check your system wide proxy settings.  Firefox uses its own internal settings, so it would be unaffected, while Chrome would hang up if there were something problematic in there.  Might want to see if the problem occurs in Internet Explorer as well (and update the question with the results).

Comment: @0xDAFACADE updated

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Chrome crashes, this probably has nothing to do with internet connectivity.

Did you try [resetting Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en)?

If resetting Chrome does not help, it will be difficult for anyone to help you without extensive knowledge of your computer setup.

Comment: I've tried to open settings, shows up the aw snap. If i re-install it, could it works?

Comment: I don't know, probably wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: well, I've tried, but when I open the [very first page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/welcome.html), it loads, but when the loads' finished, it shows "He's dead, Jim!".

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the firewall blocking Chrome application. Firewalls often block applications after update without any notification. Check your security software and completely allow Chrome.

I experienced a similar issue with Firefox. The following link contains steps to re-configure firewall for major security products.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configure-firewalls-so-firefox-can-access-internet

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Symantec virus scanner and now Chrome works fine.